# Making asynchronous requests to a Vertex AI endpoint (Google cloud platform)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I deployed a model to the model registry on Vertex AI. I added an endpoint too, and I am able to make inferences. Below is the code that I wrote (using Python 3.9.12):

```py
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# settings is a Pydantic BaseSettings subclass object
credentials_json = json.loads(settings.GCP_VERTEX_SERVICE_ACC)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    info=credentials_json
)
aiplatform.init(project=settings.GCLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER,
                location=settings.GCLOUD_LOCATION,
                credentials=credentials)
endpoint = aiplatform.Endpoint(settings.GCLOUD_SBERT_ENDPOINT_ID)

...

async def do_inference(list_strs: List[str]):

    result = endpoint.predict(instances=list_strs)
    return result.predictions
```

Right now I'm not able to make asynchronous requests. Is there a way around this? For instance, would using the `aiplatform_v1beta1.PredictionServiceAsyncClient` library be a solution? Thanks in advance!

---- EDIT -----

Below is the piece of code that did it for me in case someone else is struggling with the same thing.

```
import asyncio
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1beta1
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.protobuf import json_format
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Value

# settings is a Pydantic BaseSettings subclass object
credentials_json = json.loads(settings.GCP_VERTEX_SERVICE_ACC)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    info=credentials_json
)

client_options = {"api_endpoint": f"{settings.GCLOUD_LOCATION}-aiplatform.googleapis.com"}
client = aiplatform_v1beta1.PredictionServiceAsyncClient(credentials=credentials, client_options=client_options)

...

async def do_inference(list_strs: List[str]):

    request = aiplatform_v1beta1.PredictRequest(endpoint=endpoint)
    request.instances.extend(list_strs)
    response = await client.predict(request)
    predictions = response.predictions
    return predictions

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(do_inference())
```

This code owes a lot to @milad_raesi's answer!

Comment: For asynchronous requests, Vertex AI offers batch predictions, i.e. request a `batchPredictionsJob` directly from the `model` resource _without needing to deploy the model to an endpoint_ as in [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/overview)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use your piece of code for parallel asynchronous request to vertex but i'm still struggling somewhere.

Basically i'm using your "do_inference" task, in a for loop with different input data to predict. And then user asyncio.gather to get the results for all the tasks.
The whole thing is working BUT this line

```
    request.instances.extend(list_strs)
```

is "slow" (0.5s for a "list_strs" of ~1MB, it's quicker with smaller data) and I have no idea why. Do you (or someone else) have an idea? And how I could improve that?